# Не работает приложение на Heroku [Ошибка Н10]

Tags: python, flask, heroku

Здравствуйте. Сделал элементарное веб-приложение. Содержимое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое Procfile:

```
web: python test.py
```

Содержимое requirements.txt:

```
flask==0.12.2
```

Содержимое test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello from Flask!'

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def processing():
    return 'ffffff'
```

При переходе на мой "сайт" в браузере ошибка:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If 
you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

В консоли такое:

```
2017-06-14T17:20:04.779480+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command 'python test.py`
2017-06-14T17:20:06.120141+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-06-14T17:20:06.131327+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-06-14T17:20:06.131327+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-06-14T17:20:10.233708+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command 'python test.py`
2017-06-14T17:20:12.961724+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-06-14T17:20:12.97S600+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State chan_ed from starting to crashed
2017-06-14T17:20:12.97S600+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=demydovbb.herokuapp.com request_id=0181r73r-6be1-4ba6-8b3r-10863d8r16ae rwd="188.166.78.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-06-14T17:20:12.97S600+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/ravicon.ico" host=demydovbb.herokuapp.com request_id=a534 _ 99-45eb-4076-abe2-6712b31017d0 rwd="188.166.78.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Что я сделал не так? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена.

Нужно было в "Procfile" прописать запуск приложения через gunicorn

Comment: Стоит добавить, что этот способ описан в руководстве https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python